# Language extensions for Haskell in EclipseFP

Tags: haskell, eclipse-plugin

I recently started using eclipseFP and imported an existing project that I used to build with cabal. I have some language extensions in my cabal file to avoid repeating `{-# LANGUAGE ...}` in each source file. But I have no idea how to do the same thing with eclipseFP. Could somebody tell me how can I specify for eclipseFP what language extensions to use when building the project?

Comment: If I remember correctly, eclipseFP uses cabal to build projects. If this is the case, you should put your language options (and other options) in your cabal file, like normal.

Comment: I already have the extensions in the cabal file. I am not sure if eclipseFP is using the cabal file since it's built fine from the command line.

Comment: Did you test it to see if it works?

Comment: @NickWilde: As I said, it works fine when I compile it from the command line using cabal. But eclipsePF shows lots of errors about the language extensions in my source files. If I add `{-# LANGUAGE ...}` directive on top of a source file, the errors go away, only in that file. Of course I can repeat the same thing in all files to get rid of errors. But I wonder if I can tell eclipsePF to use these extensions globally. In cabal, it it as simple as listing them under `extension:` tag, but why eclipsePF does not recognize the extensions listed in the cabal file?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the name of cabal file is the same as the name of Eclipse project.

Comment: It is. And it shows `[proj-name built_script]` beside the project name.